# TextInput documentation don't specify onTextChanged signal

Tags: qt, qml

I can subscribe to the signal `TextChanged` in my QML code. But however i don't seem to find it in the documentation. I've searched the inherited ascending classes as well, none of them specify it. *Have I missed something or is the documentation wrong?*

I'm running **QtQuick 2.15** and looking in the [documentation for **QtQuick 2.15** TextInput QML Type](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textinput.html)

```
TextInput {
    id: firstNameInput        
    onTextChanged: {
        console.log("First name: " + text)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem I've forgot that all the [properties are assigned with handlers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#property-change-signal-handlers) in QT.

```
import QtQuick 2.15

TextInput {
    // Property 
    text: "Change this!"
    // Signal handler
    onTextChanged: console.log("Text has changed to:", text)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextField {
  id: textField

  onTextChanged: {
   console.log("Entered Text is Here == " + textField.text)
  }
}
```

It will execute each time when text is changed.
In this "textField.text" you will get the entered text.